# How to change div position with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, here's what I've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/625qofbe/1/

What I want is for the position of the "about" div, containing the Lorem Ipsum text and what should be an "X" symbol (I dunno how to link images into JSfiddle, sorry) to move, say, 30 pixels to the left when the user clicks on the "About" button in the top-left. Here's the Javascript I've been trying to do that with:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", AboutOnScreen);

function AboutOnScreen() {
    document.getElementById("about").style.left = 30px;
}
```

I've been Googling and checking the Javascript against successful little experiments like this for ages, but nothing's worked and I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

The end goal is to have the Lorem text hidden offscreen, slide in when the user clicks on About, then slide offscreen once they click the X icon. I was sure I knew in theory how do that, but I've hit a snag on step one.

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys, but weirdly the two solutions that both worked fine in JSfiddle didn't work even when I copy/pasted the code back into Sublime Text. I did, however, get the thing working by removing the "addEventListener" line and adding "onclick='AboutOnScreen()'" into the div tag for the About button. The "addEventListener" line sent up an error notification when I checked the page source (as suggested by Arindam) so I got rid of it entirely. The weird thing is I'm sure I tried that before with no success, so the solution to this head-scratcher turned out to be a confluence of all the answers below.

Comment: Use a string with proper commas... `left = '30px';` and not just `left = 30px;`

Comment: @Rikard: it's worth noting that those are quotes (`'`), not commas (`,`).

Comment: Dont build this yourself. Use jquery.

Comment: @Gregg: *why*? jQuery's all well and good (and I picked up jQuery before I moved on to plain JavaScript), but there's no need to use a library for something like this.

Comment: @DavidThomas :D sorry, I need a coffee.

Comment: @David Thomas, you make a solid point and I like the question. My thought is simply for convenience. This may not be the forum for speculation, but I believe this project, as with many projects, has more requirements than discussed here and could benefit from other convenience method. Just one persons perspective.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rikard mentioned, do the following:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", AboutOnScreen);

function AboutOnScreen() {
    document.getElementById("about").style.left = '30px';
}
```

Which should get the snippet working.
As for the sliding animation, you can use CSS3 (assuming browser support) to quickly add animation for your page.

A good resource for CSS3 animations would be http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: So both your answer and zer00ne's answer work totally fine (thanks) when I do them in JSfiddle, but when I try them in Sublime Text I'm still getting nothing. I've even gone as far as copy/pasting everything from JSfiddle into the Sublime Text document, running the page both on Safari and Google Chrome. I thought there was an issue with saving, that I'd accidentally made 2 versions of the file, but I'm able to make other visible changes without a problem.

Comment: You might have to reload the web-page using Ctrl+F5. To check that the changes got saved and propagated, just do a right-click + view-source on the web-page and verify that the editor changes got propagated.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the inline style of an element's distance value in plain JS, it's a combo of Number and String or String. So the value can be: `'430px'` or `430+'px'`.

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", AboutOnScreen);

function AboutOnScreen() {
  document.getElementById("about").style.left = 430 + 'px';
}
```

You said move to the left by 30px, which is interpreted (at least to me), as 30px from the element is positioned currently. So it was `left: 400px` so the value should be `430px` if moving 30px to the left.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/4psv5tmy/)